# Split 1 file with 2 columns

Tags: r, unix

I have 1 file containing two columns (and many rows). The first column contains the name (sample.10) and the second row contains a number. 
I need to split them into two seperate files.

I would like to attach the file, so that you can see it, however I don't know how to do it, so I have attached a picture instead:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a .csv, .txt?
at any case, you an read in a dataframe, split it into two columns, then save in two files with the extension you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have now done the dataframe. Do you know how I can split them? 
Column 1 is now called V1 and column 2 called V2

Comment: For example `write.csv(your_data_frame$V1,filepath)`?

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In you Java you can do as shown below:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class FileSplit
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("example.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);


        FileWriter writer_ = new FileWriter("output_.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter_ = new BufferedWriter(writer_);

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] str = line.split(" ");

            bufferedWriter.write(str[0]);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.newLine();

            bufferedWriter_.write(str[1]);
            bufferedWriter_.flush();
            bufferedWriter_.newLine();

        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop that will go through the columns of a dataframe and then write them to separate files. It might be helpful if you have more than two columns in the future:

```
# Put your filepath here

path <- "mypath/iris"


# Write all files

for (i in seq_along(iris)) {

  colName <- names(iris)[i]
  new_path <- paste0(path, "_", colName, ".csv")

  write.csv(iris[[i]], new_path)

}
```